# Merge two lists to make dictionary with same key Python

Tags: python

I would like to know how to change this code to NOT using the function zip. I haven’t been taught this function yet and so I want to know if there is an alternative way to retrieve the output I require?

```
list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']
list_two = [1, 2, 3, 4]

dict_1 = {}

for key, value in zip(list_one, list_two):
    if key not in dict_1:
        dict_1[key] = [value]
    else:
        dict_1[key].append(value)

print(dict_1)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'd': [4], 'c': [3]}
```

Comment: This question has no relevance to other users. `zip` is a builtin you should be using when coding Python.

Comment: @Aza checkout my solution

Comment: I would ask why should you NOT use something that you already apparently can use, and that is the most natural way of doing it. :)

Comment: I am a student and I am taking this course to learn coding. I get given worksheets to practice but can only use functions that I have been taught. In the future he will definitely be showing us how to use zip and even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip()` makes it easy to iterate through multiple lists in parallel. If you try to understand the `zip()` it would be very easy to replicate it. So, please find the explanation and example in the [official docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Below is an example code with the implementation,

```
list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']
list_two = [1,2,3,4]

dict_1={}
for index in range(len(list_one)):
    if list_one[index] not in dict_1:
        dict_1[list_one[index]]=[list_two[index]]
    else:
        dict_1[list_one[index]].append(list_two[index])
print(dict_1)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}
```

Comment: I bet OP does not want to use `enumerate` either.

Comment: This is also a good way but I haven’t been taught enumerate as well unfortunately

Comment: Ok @Aza, then go by the old way of iterating things!

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this:

```
l1 = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']

l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Dict comprehension to initialize keys: list pairs
dct = {x: [] for x in l1}

# Append value related to key
for i in range(len(l1)):
    dct[l1[i]].append(l2[i])

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4]}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well too! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite like this without any library.

```
list_one = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd']
list_two = [1,2,3,4]
dict_1={}
if len(list_one) == len(list_two):
    for i in range(len(list_one)):
        if list_one[i] not in dict_1:
            dict_1[list_one[i]]=[list_two[i]]
        else:
            dict_1[list_one[i]].append(list_two[i])
print(dict_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two lists always have the same length, you can circumvent the use of `zip()` by iterating over the indices:

```
dict_1 = {}

for i in range(len(list_one)):
    key = list_one[i]
    value = list_two[i]

    if key not in dict_1:
        dict_1[key] = [value]
    else:
        dict_1[key].append(value)
        
print(dict_1)
```

As others have said, this is not a recommended way to do this, because the code using `zip()` is more readable, and `zip()` is a built-in function, so there shouldn't be any reason not to use it.